# Cannot assign to nullable double variable

Tags: c#, nullable, novacode-docx

I have used DocX library to create a .docx document from text in my TextBoxs. 
I have a problem that I can't assign size of nullable variable to other variable (only can assign to value)

```
var infoFormatting = new Formatting();
infoFormatting.Size = txt_Info.Font.Size //txt_Info is a TextBox
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you set the Size in an object initializer?

Comment: Which variable is nullable?

Comment: I have investigated and the `infoFormatting.Size` is `double?` and `Font.Size` is `single`. I don't see what could be the problem other than casting/converting source to `double`.

Comment: @NedStoyanov , infoFormatting.Size is a nullable variable

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
infoFormatting.Size = (double)txt_Info.Font.Size;
```

Comment: I tried like that but my programs still have this error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in DocX.dll
Additional information: Size